# Searching in a sorted 2D matrix

Tags: java, interview-questions, search, matrix, binary-search

If I was at an interview, and wrote this code, what would you think? Please be brutal.

Time it took to wrote it: 13 minutes

Problem:

> Write an efficient algorithm that searches for a value in an m x n
> matrix. This matrix has the following properties:
>
> Integers in each row are sorted from left to right. The first integer
> of each row is greater than the last integer of the previous row. For
> example,
>
> Consider the following matrix:
>
> ```
> [
>   [1,   3,  5,  7],
>   [10, 11, 16, 20],
>   [23, 30, 34, 50]
> ]
> ```
>
> Given target = 3, return true.

---

```
 public boolean searchMatrix(int[][] matrix, int target) {
    int lastCol = matrix[0].length-1;
    int row=0;
    while(row!=matrix.length && lastCol>=0){
        if(matrix[row][lastCol]==target){
            return true;
        }
        if(matrix[row][lastCol]>target){
            lastCol--;
            if(binarySearch(matrix[row], 0, lastCol, target)!=-1){
                return true;
            }
        }
        row++;
    }
    return false;
}
public int binarySearch(int[] arr, int low, int high, int target){
    while(low<=high){
        int mid = (low + high)/2;
        if(arr[mid]==target){
            return mid;
        }
        else if(arr[mid]<target){
            low = mid+1;
        }
        else if(arr[mid]>target){
            high = mid-1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Space complexity = \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$
Time Complexity = \$\mathcal{O}(\log(n!))\$

Comment: A better way to do this is to treat it like a single dimension sorted array, and perform your binary search on _that_, using modulo and division to extract your values from the 2d array.

Comment: Can you explain how I'd use modulo, a bit weak with that operation.

Comment: something like `row = mid/ arr[0].length()` and `col = mid % arr[0].length()`. If no-one else does, I'll post an answer tomorrow, but I need to get some sleep.

Comment: O(n!)... are you saying n factorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is not efficient (that's the brutal part of the answer).

Searching in a list of  t values is a task that can be accomplished using \$\mathcal{O}(\log(t))\$ comparisons. Here we have \$t=m*n\$ values so it should be accomplished using \$\mathcal{O}(\log(m*n)) = \mathcal{O}(\log(m))+\mathcal{O}(\log(n))\$ comparisons. I suspect your algorithm may execute the while loop about `matrix.length` times so it is not \$\mathcal{O}(\log(m))\$ (where m is the number of rows).

The algorithm could work in the following way:

- If the searched value is smaller then the first column in the first row, then the searched value is not contained in the matrix.
- Then do a binary search on the first column of the matrix to find the largest entry smaller or equal to the searched value.
- If the value found matches, you are done.
- Otherwise, do a binary search on the row found.
- If the value found matches the searched value, you are done;
- otherwise, the searched value is not in the matrix.

Another way is to treat the problem like a single dimension sorted array as it is proposed in the [comment of @Azar](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45783/searching-in-a-sorted-2d-matrix#comment80254_45809).

Even a small piece of code can have [a lot of errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Implementation_issues) so it does make sense to try to use [library methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) to accomplish this task and not implement the binary search by yourself (but I don't know if this is the intention of the poser of the problem).

This blog entry discusses an [example of a buggy implementation in Java](http://googleresearch.blogspot.co.at/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html). It references the following [SUN  bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5045582) because there was an erroneous implementation of the binary search even in the JDK.

Comment: Really not more complicated at all, but yes, it has the same runtime, `O(log(mn))`.

Comment: @Azar: If it is not more complicated I am curious about your answer.

Comment: Sorry, been a little busy lately. Here you go: http://pastebin.com/t59ZnJFQ

Comment: @Azar: The overhead is insignificant so I will remove the recommendation from my posting. You avoided the mentioned bug. Nevertheless I would recommand   to use a library.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is very well done, especially for 12 minutes.

---

### Similar solutions

That solution is very similar to GeekforGeek solution.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-in-row-wise-and-column-wise-sorted-matrix/

The problem is slightly different (more generic).

Compare

```
class GFG {

/* Searches the element x in mat[][]. If the
element is found, then prints its position
and returns true, otherwise prints "not found"
and returns false */
private static void search(int[][] mat, int n, int x) {

    int i = 0, j = n - 1; // set indexes for top right
    // element

    while (i < n && j >= 0) {
        if (mat[i][j] == x) {
            System.out.print("n Found at " + i + " " + j);
            return;
        }
        if (mat[i][j] > x) {
            j--;
        } else // if mat[i][j] < x
        {
            i++;
        }
    }

    System.out.print("n Element not found");
    return; // if ( i==n || j== -1 )
}
}
// This code is contributed by Arnav Kr. Mandal.
```

---

### Complexity analysis.

Your complexity analysis was wrong.
Let A matrix n x m. The complexity is O(m log(n)).

Proof:
For every movement in the vertical direction, the algorithm performs a new binary search in the horizontal direction.

If the matrix is a columnar matrix... the complexity will be O(m), for example.

---

### Room for improvement

A better solution would be using the binary search in both directions (what keep working for more generic problems). Complexity is O(log(n) * log(m))

Or take usage of total ordering. More efficient but less generic. Complexity is O(log (n) + log(m))

See:
 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-element-sorted-matrix/

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I just happened to see it today.

[This answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/223052/71574) says that your complexity analysis is wrong.  That's not quite true.

Your \$\mathcal{O}(\log(n!))\$ is correct if we assume that \$n\$ is the total amount of data and that \$\mathcal{O}(\log{n^n})\$ is \$\mathcal{O}(\log(n!))\$.  That's generally considered to be true because \$n^n\$ is the product of \$n\$ things of magnitude \$n\$ and \$n!\$ is the product of \$n\$ things of average magnitude \$\frac{n}{2}\$.  Also \$\mathcal{O}(\log{n^n})\$ is \$\mathcal{O}(n\log{n})\$.  We're also assuming that the row and column length can be described as \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ which is trivially true if their product is \$n\$.  But this is a rather loose complexity bound.  If the matrix is square, \$\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}\log{n})\$ would be tighter.

It is probably simpler and tighter though to describe your algorithm as being \$\mathcal{O}(m\log{n})\$ (or \$\mathcal{O}(\log{n^m})\$) where \$m\$ is the number of rows and \$n\$ is the number of columns (so not the same value as the last paragraph).  This entirely gets around any guessing about the shape of the matrix.  So \$mn\$ is the number of data elements.  And as [previously noted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45809/71574), \$\mathcal{O}(\log{mn})\$ is possible (may also be written \$\mathcal{O}(\log{m} + \log{n})\$).

The \$\mathcal{O}(m\log{n})\$ is also easier to explain.  You potentially iterate through \$m\$ rows and on each row, you do \$\log{n}\$ operations (the binary search).  The simple product then is \$m\log{n}\$.  Rewriting that as \$\log{n^m}\$ is true, but requires an extra step to justify.  And I spent a whole paragraph on explaining why \$\mathcal{O}(mn\log{mn})\$ is \$\mathcal{O}(\log((mn)!))\$.  So while \$\mathcal{O}(\log(n!))\$ is technically correct if \$n\$ is the total number of elements, \$\mathcal{O}(m\log{n})\$ (where \$n\$ is the number of columns) is generally a better description.  It is less obfuscated and easier to understand.

Another issue is that I have no idea how you arrived at \$\mathcal{O}(\log(n!))\$.  Even though it is correct, I'm not convinced that you know why it is correct.  It can often be useful to give a short justification of your thinking, as I did with \$\mathcal{O}(m\log{n})\$.  Because it makes a big difference whether you accidentally hit a correct value or if you performed the analysis correctly.

Often defining one's \$n\$ is an important part of complexity analysis.  In this case, using it as the number of columns rather than the amount of data makes things simpler.